# Why do i still get ModuleNotFoundError when i try to import textract even after successfully installing the module?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, spyder

I have successfully installed textract module using `pip install textract` on windows 10 after following [these](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/194#issuecomment-356203467) steps, but when i try to import textract(using Spyder IDE python 3.6.10 anaconda), i get *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textract'*.
In command prompt when i enter the `pip list` command, i can see the mentioned module version 1.6.3, but when i enter `conda list` i can't find it.
I have added the paths in the system environment variables for conda, and also for pip.
I am new to python, did i miss anything? or is it that i can't import modules installed from pip and it should be installed with conda?

Comment: My guess is that the Python installation where you added the library is not the Python installation used to execute the program

Comment: you were right, i looked for the location of the installed library and copied it to the default location and it worked. Thank you problem solved.